# Advantages of using a Powdered iron core for an Inductor

Tags: inductor, core

I was suggested to use an iron core for an inductor. I found that it has low permeabilty and good stability, but how does that make it a good material for the core. And is there a way to figure out the saturation condition for it?

The one i am using is: http://www.micrometals.com/pcparts/torcore5.html  - T-130 - 52

Comment: http://www.micrometals.com/pcparts/PC_L.pdf has lots of data about the materials.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most applications of iron powder cores are substitutions of inductors made of ferrite cores. These applications include DC/DC converter output filter inductors and power factor correction inductors.

In these applications you need the energy storage capability (proportional to \$ B \times H \$; all quantities are magnitudes)  of the inductor core. Ferrite cores have a high permeability so you need to introduce an air gap to reduce this permeability, thus increasing the magnetic field \$H\$ strength needed to magnetize the core to a flux density \$ B \$. This air gap has a severe disadvantage: within the air gap the relative permeability is reduced to unity and this causes the flux to exit the core and enter the winding, leading to eddy current losses in the winding. The power loss density is concentrated around the air gap, so there is the risk of a hot spot.

Iron powder cores do not need the additional air gap since it is integrated into the material and, in consequence, spread within the complete core volume. This reduces the eddy current losses in the winding and the remaining eddy current losses are distributed throughout the winding length.

Furthermore, energy storage is limited by the saturation flux density. In ferrite this saturation flux density is about 400 mT and decreases with temperature. In iron powder cores saturation flux densities of more than 1 T can be utilized, depending on the material.

As you mentioned Micrometals core: Micrometals, Inc. offers an [Inductor Design Software](http://www.micrometals.com/software_index.html) that can be used to design basic inductors including power loss calculations.

Comment: Since B and H are linearly related (ignoring M - magnetization) could you explain why you wrote BXH ?

Comment: For ferrite cores this linearity assumption is valid as almost all the energy is stored in the air gap. In powder cores the energy density is distributed in the core volume and because of this, besides other reasons, B and H are not linearly related.

Comment: More to the point, perhaps you can explain how the material generates a different vector direction that justifies the use of a cross product?

Comment: It's not a cross product, B and H are scalars in this equation. If they were vectors (usually denoted by **boldface**) you would have to use the dot product to get the correct result.

Comment: Well that _ONE_ convention, there are many. I suggest you edit the post to make that clear.

Comment: The energy in a core is \$\frac{L I^2}{2}\$ where L = \$\frac{B}{H}\$ and I is proportional to H so I guess energy is proportional to B x H. Sorry for interrupting this interesting conversation.

Comment: @Andy aka: as much as I know B/H is µ not L (µ is an intensive quantity; while L is an extensive quantity) and BH is the energy **density** (not energy).

Comment: @curd, yes it is a tad confusing what I said. Mu and L are proportional is my only excuse for this confusion.

Answer (score 4):

If you know what flux density the material saturates at and you know what the BH curve for the mateial is you can calculate H: -

H = \$ \dfrac{ampere \times turns}{effective\space length\space of\space core}\$

The effective length of the core should be quoted in the product spec but for a toroid you can calculate it easily - take the mean radius (R) to the mid-point of the core and use \$2\pi R\$ as that length.

Comment: +1 I just want to add here, that if there is an air/plastic gap this doesn't apply anymore. Since most of the magnetic voltage will drop there. Hence H drops heavily inside the core.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly.